# Git-like pager/editor management

Tags: c, git, development-environment

A little bit of confusion over here.

I am trying to reproduce Git's behavior regarding pagers and editors (as I think Git developers already done good (maybe the best) design choices in this scope).

While trying to break it down I found that Git uses the pager/editor set to the environment variable `$PAGER/$EDITOR`. However even if `$PAGER/$EDITOR` is not set, git still opens a pager/editor.

For example, on my system when I run.

```
$ PAGER=cat git log
```

Git works as expected and uses `cat` to print the data.

But I (obviously) don't have to do that. And even if `$PAGER` is not set, which is the case by default on my system according to the following command.

```
$ echo $PAGER

$
```

Git still can open a nice, well chosen pager (`less` in my case) to print data properly.

This looks neat! This is (to a certain extent) the behavior I am looking for.

But I am not able to find out how this is implemented. Is the default pager/editor is chosen at build time? If so how can I do the same knowing that I am using `autotools` as my build system. And by how I mean how should the option for choosing the default pager/editor look like? And is there any specific `autoconf`/`automake` macro(s) dedicated to this.

Is this a dynamic configuration (Can be changed after the build in a configuration file)? And if so, I'd like to take a look at this configuration file. Where can I find it?

Maybe this is more complicated than that and Git is able to guess and automatically choose the pager/editor by it self. And if this is the case, I'd like to know how it does that.

Any advice or pointers will be helpful. Not necessarily about how Git is implementing the stuff. Therefore I'd like to point out that the package I am building is intended to be cross-platform, easily compilable/cross-compilable to non linux-like platforms. Which may or may not have a convenient command line editor/pager (BTW. can I support GUI editors?) ie. a binary provider might have to include the editor/pager to the deployment package. I want to make that process as easy as possible (the binary provider should not look at the code).

Basically I want to make design choices as best as I can afford. With a little boost from you guys I can do even better.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not rocket science. Just read the environment variable, and if it's empty decide on a tool to use. Choose some sensible defaults like `less` for pager, and `vi` for editor since there's a pretty good chance that they will be present on any *nix machine.

Comment: @Mael lol, yes I know. It's not that difficult. But I am wandering if it'll be a good idea to, for example enable the package builder to choose which will be the default pager/editor and what are the standards for that (what should the builder provide as an option to the configure script to be able to choose an editor/pager). Also the package is intended to work on non *nix platforms as well which may not contain a good editor/pager. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @janos's answer and by taking a quick look through [Git's source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/pager.c) code.

> ```
> const char *git_pager(int stdout_is_tty)
> {
>   const char *pager;
>
>   if (!stdout_is_tty)
>       return NULL;
>
>   pager = getenv("GIT_PAGER");
>   if (!pager) {
>       if (!pager_program)
>           read_early_config(core_pager_config, NULL);
>       pager = pager_program;
>   }
>   if (!pager)
>       pager = getenv("PAGER");
>   if (!pager)
>       pager = DEFAULT_PAGER;
>   if (!*pager || !strcmp(pager, "cat"))
>       pager = NULL;
>
>   return pager;
> }
> ```

I managed to understand exactly Git's behavior among pagers/editors. **Which is not as obvious as one might think**.

As a first step Git checks for the environnement variable `$GIT_PAGER`/`$GIT_EDITOR`. If it's not set it checks the configuration file in `~/.gitconfig`. If it doesn't find a pager/editor there. It looks into the environnement variable `$PAGER`/`$EDITOR`. If it is not set it uses the code defined (fall-back) parameter `DEFAULT_PAGER`/`DEFAULT_EDITOR` which in its turn is set to `"less"`/`"vi"` unless saying differently at build-time by specifying `--with-pager`/`--with-editor` to the `configure` script.

In most linux distributions the fall-back is set to `"pager"`/`"editor"` as they hold a symbolic link to a distribution defined pager/editor binary in `/usr/bin/pager`/`/usr/bin/editor`. In my case:

```
$ readlink -e /usr/bin/editor 
/bin/nano
$ readlink -e /usr/bin/pager
/bin/less
```

The editor management is a bit more complicated than that (I think there is some problems related to old/basic terminals). But I think this will do right now. I will look into editor subtilises later on and edit if I think it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) (search for "core.pager"),
the default pager is the `less` command.

When building Git from source, you can find supported configuration options by running `./configure --help` and filter using a suitable `grep`, for example:

```
./configure --help | grep -i pager
```

This outputs:

> ```
>   --with-pager=VALUE      Use VALUE as the fall-back pager instead of 'less'.
>                           does not specify a pager to use through alternate
>                           methods. eg: /usr/bin/pager
> ```

Comment: Interesting! It's a build defined parameter then! Thank you.